# create child div in a parent div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following div structure

```
<div id="main_div">
    <div id="lastChildDiv"></div>
</div>
```

now I want to create or append a new `div` above the div id of `lastChildDiv`. Then how to do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
$('#main_div').prepend('<div id="new_div">...</div>');
```

Answer (score 12):

Use [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/) to append the newly created element:

```
$('#lastChildDiv').before('<div></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .before()

```
$('#lastChildDiv').before('<div></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var myNewDiv = '<div id='someId'></div>';
    $('#main_div').html(myNewDiv);
```

or:

```
    var myNewDiv = '<div id='someId'></div>';
    $('#main_div').append(myNewDiv);
```

Comment: This way the old content will be either overwritten or the new content will be placed *after* the element